# Android, calculate the how long time between now and 'n'

Tags: android, datetime

i have method for execute some task using AlarmManager, but i have to calculate the time before execute it,
for example, the current time is 10:24 and the task must be executed at 11:00 so, how i calculate how long time between 10:24 to 11:00

example
CurrentTime = 10:30
TargetTime  = 11:00

long time between 10:30 and 11:00 is 30 Minute and i'll convert it to milisecond

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
You can get difference between two times using Date class in java

Date date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
Date date2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");

getTimeDiff(date1,date2,TimeUnit.MINUTES);
public static long getTimeDiff(Date date1, Date date2, TimeUnit timeUnit) {
    long diffInMillies = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
    return timeUnit.convert(diffInMillies,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that helpful, anyway, can i do it using Calendar ?

Comment: Welcome. And yes you can do it with Calendar class also